# Rails - Activerecord conditions with enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums

I have an Item model and a UserItem model.  An Item has many UserItems.

Both models use Enum:

`enum status: [ :pending, :approved]`

I need to query Item to return user_items where item.id != 1, item.status is approved, and user_items.status is pending.  I am having trouble with the correct syntax

`Item.joins(:user_items).where( "items.id != ? and items.status = ? and user_items.status = ?", 1, ???, ???)`

What is the correct way to write this query?

Comment: Do you need items where any of `user_items.status` is pending? Or where all are pending? What about items that do not have any?

Comment: Sorry I was a little unclear I will fix the question. I need to return user_items where the parent Item is approved but id not equal to 1

Comment: I mean that it there's an "approved" `Item` with two `UserItems`, one of the latter is approved, one not - should the former be selected?

Comment: @vasfed So all the returned user_items must be pending, the parent item must be approved and the parent item id must not be equal to 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're selecting UserItems, and assuming you have `belongs_to :item` on the other side of `has_many` relation query will look like

```
UserItem.pending.joins(:item).merge(Item.approved.where.not(id:1))
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this earlier, but what if this was part of a method that I wanted to keep in my Item.rb model.  Would it still work the way you have it?

Comment: @user4584963 technically it does not matter. PS. updated answer with scopes and `Relation#merge`

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
UserItem.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN items.id = user_items.id").where("items.id != ? AND items.status = ? AND user_items.status = ?", 1, "approved","pending")
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you don't want to use scope

Item.joins(:user_item).where( "items.id != ? and items.status = ? and user_items.status = ?", 1, Item.statuses[:pending], UserItem.statuses[:approved])

But it is always nicer to use scopes.